# Clojure JDBC transaction not rolling back on BatchUpdateException in HSQL

Tags: jdbc, clojure, hsqldb, apache-commons-dbcp

I'm writing a Clojure program using clojure.java.jdbc.  I'm using DBCP to pool connections to HSQL 2.2.8.  I have a (transaction) block in which I test if a schema exists, and if not, creates it and a bunch of tables.  One of the statements after the schema create (I believe a MERGE statement) throws a BatchUpdateException.

The issue is that the schema create is not rolled back on the BatchUpdateException, even though they're part of the same (transaction) block.

Are there known issues with Clojure JDBC interacting with DBCP or HSQL?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind.

Transactions don't apply to schema changes, apparently.  WTF?

Comment: Structural (schema) changes don't rollback on certain databases. They do on MS SQL, but not on Oracle, for example. Since something can be said for both behaviors, it's good to check which version is used in your database.

Comment: You can check the behavior of a DB with [`DatabaseMetaData.dataDefinitionCausesTransactionCommit()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#dataDefinitionCausesTransactionCommit()) and related methods